Angular 17 Search Term is not updating on UI
I have an issue with updating the ui as needed base on search in my angular 17 application. Base on console logs the filter template list is being updated base on the search term no problem. So I am not sure why isn't the home component updating.
I have the search bar in the app.component and I do have a service class to talk to both app.component and home.component.
App.Component.ts


import { Component, inject } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { HomeComponent } from './Components/home/home.component';
import { Templates} from './templates';
import { TemplateComponent } from './Components/template-market/template-market.component';
import { TemplateService } from './Services/template.service';
import { Search } from './Services/search';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [
    HomeComponent,
    RouterModule,
    CommonModule,
    TemplateComponent,
  ],
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrl: './app.component.css'
})
export class AppComponent{
  title = 'ContentTemplateMarketPlace';
  templateList: Templates[] =[];
  filteredTemplateList: Templates[] =[];
  templateService: TemplateService = inject(TemplateService);

  showDropdown = false;
  menu=false;

  search: Search = inject(Search);

  
  constructor(){
    this.templateService.getAllTemplates().then((templateList: Templates[])=>{
      this.templateList = templateList;
      // Initialize filteredTemplateList with all templates initially
      this.filteredTemplateList = templateList;
      console.log('templateList:', this.templateList);
    });
  } 


  toggleDropdown() {
    this.showDropdown = !this.showDropdown;
  }
  toggleMenu(){
    this.menu = !this.menu;
  }


  applyFilter(text: string) {
    const results= this.filterResults(text);
    this.search.updateSearchResults(results)
    console.log('applyFilter:', results )
  }
  //TODO: FIGURE OUT WHY IT DOESN'T UPDATE ON UI. WORKS IN CONSOLE.LOGS
  filterResults(text:string): any[]{
    console.log(text)
    if(!text){
      console.log('Text is empty.');
      this.filteredTemplateList=this.templateList;
      console.log('Filtered template list:', this.filteredTemplateList);
      return this.templateList;
    }

    console.log('Text is not empty.');
    this.filteredTemplateList = this.templateList.filter(template => 
      template?.title.toLowerCase().includes(text.toLowerCase())
    );
    console.log('Filtered template list:', this.filteredTemplateList);
    return this.filteredTemplateList;
  }
}



App.component.html
<div class="nav-search">
            <form >
                <input type="text" placeholder="Search for anything" #filter >
                <button class="primary" type="button" (click)="applyFilter(filter.value)">Search</button>
            </form>
</div>

Search.ts
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";
import { BehaviorSubject} from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root'
})
export class Search{
    private searchResultsSource = new BehaviorSubject<any[]>([]);
    currentSearchResults = this.searchResultsSource.asObservable();

    constructor(){}

    updateSearchResults(results: any[]){
        this.searchResultsSource.next(results);
        console.log('searchService:', results);
    }
}


Home.component.ts
import { Component, inject } from '@angular/core';
import { TemplateComponent } from '../template-market/template-market.component';
import { CommonModule } from "@angular/common";
import { Templates} from '../../templates';
import { TemplateService } from '../../Services/template.service';
import { FilterComponent } from '../filter/filter.component';
import { Search } from '../../Services/search';


@Component({
    selector: 'app-home',
    standalone: true,
    imports:[
        CommonModule,
        TemplateComponent,
        FilterComponent
    ],
    templateUrl: './home.component.html',
    styleUrl:'./home.component.css'
})

export class HomeComponent{
    templateList: Templates[] =[];
    filteredTemplateList: Templates[] =[];
    templateService: TemplateService = inject(TemplateService);
    
    filteredCategories: any;
    filteredSortBy:string= '';

    searchResults:any[] = [];
    searchActivated: boolean = false;

    constructor(private search: Search){
        this.templateService.getAllTemplates().then((templateList: Templates[])=>{
            this.templateList = templateList;
            this.filteredTemplateList = templateList;
        });
        this.search.currentSearchResults.subscribe(results =>{
            this.searchResults = results;
            this.searchActivated = this.searchResults.length > 0; 
            // console.log( 'ngOnInit: Showing up in home.component when page reloads')
        });
    }

    applyFilter(event:any){
        console.log('Selected categories:', event.categories); 
        this.filteredCategories = event.categories;
        this.filteredSortBy = event.sortBy;
        this.filterData();
    }
    applySorting(sortBy: string) {
        this.filteredSortBy = sortBy;
        this.filterData();
    }

    filterData() {
        // Create a copy of the original templateList to avoid modifying it directly
        this.filteredTemplateList = [...this.templateList];

            // If no categories are selected, show all items
        if (!this.filteredCategories || Object.values(this.filteredCategories).every(category => !category)) {
            return;
        }
    
        // Filter based on selected categories
        this.filteredTemplateList = this.filteredTemplateList.filter((Template) => {
          // Check if the template belongs to any selected category
          for (const category in this.filteredCategories) {
            if (
              this.filteredCategories[category] &&
              Template.template_type.includes(category)
            ) {
              console.log('Matched template:', Template);
              return true;
            }
          }
          return false; // Exclude the template if it doesn't belong to any selected category
        });

        console.log('Value of this.filteredSortBy:', this.filteredSortBy);
        // Sort the filtered list based on selected sorting option
        switch (this.filteredSortBy) {
            case 'title':
                this.filteredTemplateList.sort((a, b) => a.title.localeCompare(b.title));
                break;
            case 'created_by':
                this.filteredTemplateList.sort((a, b) => a.created_by.name.localeCompare(b.created_by.name));
                break;
            case 'mostPopular':
                // You need to implement logic to sort by popularity (e.g., review count & rating)
                break;
            default:
                // Default sorting option, no sorting needed
                break;
                
        }
        
    }
    
    
}

Home.component.html
<div class="hero">
    <h2>This will hold the total search results</h2>
</div>
<div class="wrapper">
    <section class="app-filter-container">
        <app-filter (filterApplied)="applyFilter($event)"></app-filter>
    </section>
    
    <section class="results">
        <app-template-market
        *ngFor="let template of filteredTemplateList"
        [template]="template">
        </app-template-market>
    </section>
</div>

